# DocuSignApi - Envelope status returned as "template"

Tags: docusignapi

I just started suing DocuSign's sandbox to test some of the API call that I plan to use on my website. I was testing the call that returns the information about a particular template. I set up a template in my sandbox and emailed it to myself. I then tried to get the template info by making this call:

```
Envelope envInfo = envelopesApi.GetEnvelope(accountId, envelopeId);
```

In the JSON that I get back the value for "status" is "template", which is not one of the possible statuses according to DocuSign (https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Status%20Changes.htm). If anything it should be "Delivered". Has anyone had a similar issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my own dumb error - I was checking the **template ID** instead of the envelope ID.